# Python re.findall float return unable to sum returned values

Tags: python, floating-point, sum, string-conversion

I'm using re.findall to return the float from a specific line in a file:

```
mealReturnValue = re.findall("\d+\.\d+",lines[2])
```

Example file line it pulls from: "The total bill was 400.00 "

This will return a list of numbers as follows:

```
[['400.00'], ['210.0'], ['400.00']]
```

I'm then trying to sum the list, however, it throws the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "TotalSpend.py", line 25, in <module>
    totalSpend = sum(mealReturn)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'list'
```

This seems to be a function of the re.findall as i've been able to do this manually by generating an array of the same numbers.

For example:

```
i = [400.00, 210.0, 400.00]

print sum(i)
```

So i don't know what the real problem is here, i cant seem to convert the re.findall to a float i can use in the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

For extra clarity the entire code file:

```
import os
import sys
import re


dirListing = os.listdir('C:\Users\joshnathan\Desktop\LPTHW')
mealReturn =[] # Array of returned meal values
numberOfMeals = 0

print "Which meal do you want to calculate?"
meal = raw_input(">>")


for item in dirListing:
    if meal in item:
        numberOfMeals += 1
        fileName = open(item, 'r')
        lines = fileName.readlines()
        mealReturnValue = re.findall('\d+\.\d+',lines[2])
        mealReturn.append(mealReturnValue)
        print mealReturn


print numberOfMeals
totalSpend = sum(mealReturn)
print totalSpend
```

Thanks
Joshua

Comment: *This will return a list of numbers as follows* - ummm... `re.findall` won't return that... are you sure you're not doing something else that you're not showing us? (such as appending to a list each time?)

Comment: Added the full code file for reference. Thanks for the update!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
In [1]: sum([float(i[0]) for i in a])
Out[1]: 1010.0
```

Considered `a` as your result. You are trying to perform `sum` operation on list of list. And it's in string format. You need to convert to `float` and make it as a single list. Then you can perform the `sum` operation.

**Steps**

1 . Make it as a single list

```
In [2]: [i[0] for i in a]
Out[2]: ['400.00', '210.0', '400.00']
```

2 . Convert all elements to `float`

```
In [3]: [float(i[0]) for i in a]
Out[3]: [400.0, 210.0, 400.0]
```

3 . Perform the sum operation.

```
In [4]: sum([float(i[0]) for i in a])
Out[4]: 1010.0
```

**Edit**

`mealReturnValue = re.findall('\d+\.\d+',lines[2])` will return something like this `[['400.00']]` So you can convert it into float there itself like this `mealReturnValue = float(re.findall('\d+\.\d+',lines[2])[0])`. And instead of `append` into a string you can add up on a variable. `mealReturnValue += re.findall('\d+\.\d+',lines[2])`. To use like this you have to declare the `mealReturnValue`. Like this `mealReturnValue = 0`

Change you code like this

```
totalSpend = 0
for item in dirListing:
    if meal in item:
        numberOfMeals += 1
        fileName = open(item, 'r')
        lines = fileName.readlines()
        totalSpend += float(re.findall('\d+\.\d+',lines[2])[0])

print numberOfMeals
print totalSpend
```

Comment: Hello Rahul, thanks for this update it explains a lot. If i understand correctly despite using re.findall to pull out variables that appear as a float it stores them as a string. So i need to convert the variables in the list from string to float. Based on your example this first generates the list and converts the list to float after?
Is there any way to do this on the fly so for each variable it stores it as a float the first time around? I've added my full code above for reference im just wondering i can force mealReturnValue to be a float when it is stored?

Comment: @ImNewToThis Updated my question check it.

Comment: thanks for the update on this. Makes complete sense. Really appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to sum a list of lists of strings.

When summing, you should sum the values as floats:

```
sum(float(num[0]) for num in mealReturnValue)
>> 1010.0
```

Comment: Thank you very much for this. This worked very well. Can i ask though how i store the variables in a list as floats so i don't have to amend them at the end?